# Desktop entry equivalents on Windows and macOS?

Tags: installation, desktop, desktop-environments

What are the equivalents of Freedesktop's [.desktop entry](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) for different operating systems?

I'm making a Python package that would allow managing and registering such entries for other python packages that would define GUI interface, so a user of a such package could easily find it in app menu.

I'm aiming for as best multi-system support as I'll manage to achieve, so any information about different popular operating systems than only Windows and macOS is welcome.

Comment: What kind of .desktop entry – app menu item? autostart? mimetype handler? In other words, what you trying to *achieve* will define the tool you need to use, as it's rarely the case that all functions are grouped the same way in every OS.

Comment: @u1686_grawity While reviewing my question, it seems like I removed this information: I'm mostly interested in app menu item desktop entry.

Comment: Have you looked at the materials published by the respective OSes publishers regarding this?

Comment: @music2myear I tried to search for them, but I don't know how they are called for different operating systems, so I only got irrelevant results...

Comment: For macOS, search for "macOS Application Bundle".

Comment: I happen to have [some links and some code you may steal](https://gitlab.com/oskog97/anonymine/-/tree/master/desktop?ref_type=heads#macos)

Comment: @OskarSkog Thanks a lot!